# my adsense ads not displaying for my active adsense account but previously it got cancelled

Tags: blogs, blogger, ads, adsense

( http://bloggerbandwidth.blogspot.com ) On my blog I had previously it associated with some other adsesne account but that adsense account got disapproved 
so my adsesne ads  are not showing but one month before I got approved on other adsense account and move my side to adsense associated account and i paste my code on my side but blank space is came but ads are not come so what to do any one knows about this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: Looking at your other question, you might need to read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Same occurred with me, but even did not tried to fix it

Comment: Also check if any adblocker plugin is not activated in your browser

Comment: but other ads are coming except adsense ads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you change your blogspot name than adsense ads are showing automatically . But another important thing is. If you rename the blog that is affect your page traffic.you definitely lose your page visitors.

Comment: Not an answer, much less one that should be self-accepted. Best idea is to delete your entire question, although it will be soon enough anyway.